# How to call checkbox from a different class file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, checkbox, datagrid

I have a DataGrid displaying values from a database. The DataGrid is then populated in a different class file. But I have a checkbox in the html code checking if it is checked or not. When the checkbox is checked I want to load the RevToDate column from the DataGrid. So I'm getting an error: chkRevToDate does not exist. 
So how do I call the chkRevToDate checkbox in a different class?

Code for DataGrid in a file called Customer.aspx.cs:

```
<div runat="server" id="dvMainGrid" class="dvResultsLookup">
    <asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tblResults" OnItemDataBound="dgList_ItemCreated" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="dgCustomer_Sort" ID="dgCustomers" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="loading" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Customer.aspx?CustID={0}" DataNavigateUrlField="ID" DataTextField="AccountCode" HeaderText="A/C Code" SortExpression="AccountCode"></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="VATNo" HeaderText="VAT No" SortExpression="VATNo"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CurrencyDesc" HeaderText="Currency" SortExpression="CurrencyDesc"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RevToDate" HeaderText="Rev To Date (Net)" Visible="false" SortExpression="RevToDate"></asp:BoundColumn> 
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

And in the same class as the DataGrid I have the code for the checkbox

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkRevToDate" Checked="false" />
```

Code for loading values into DataGrid in a file called Customer.cs:

```
public static DataGrid BuildGrid(bool IncludeContacts)
{
    DataGrid NewDg = new DataGrid();

    NewDg.DataKeyField = "ID";
    NewDg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    NewDg.CssClass = "tblResults draggable";
    NewDg.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "tblResultsHeader";
    NewDg.AlternatingItemStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyleAlt";
    NewDg.ItemStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyle";
    NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("VATNo", "VAT No"));
    NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("CurrencyDesc", "Currency"));

    if (chkRevToDate.Checked) //error
    {
        NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("RevToDate", "Re To Date (Net)"));
    }
    return NewDg;
}
```

Is there a way to call chkRevToDate in a different class?

Comment: You should provide a public property in your page with the `DataGrid` and the `CheckBox`. This property simply returns a bool: `public bool ShowRevToDateColumn
        {
            get { return chkRevToDate.Checked; }
            set { chkRevToDate.Checked = value; }
        }` Then you need an instance of your page in the other file.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok thanks. What do I need to do to create the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass checkbox reference on BuildGrid function in customer class than you can access this check box on BuildGrid function

Code edited as per your Code

```
public static DataGrid BuildGrid(bool IncludeContacts , CheckBox chkRevToDate )
{
 if (chkRevToDate.Checked) 
    {
            NewDg.Columns.Add(Load.CreateBoundColumn("RevToDate", "Re To Date (Net)"));
    }
}
```

you can call function in Customer.aspx.cs like that

`ClassName.BuildGrid(true,chkRevToDate);` //chkRevToDate is Checkbox in you aspx file

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a public property in your page with the `DataGrid` and the `CheckBox`. This property simply returns a `bool`:

```
public bool ShowRevToDateColumn 
{ 
    get { return chkRevToDate.Checked; } 
    set { chkRevToDate.Checked = value; } 
}
```

Then you need an instance of your page in the other file.

You should not *create* the instance, it exists already. If the class is  an utility class with static methods,  you can use `HttpContext.Current`:

```
PageClassName page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as PageClassName;
if (page != null)
{
   bool checked = page.ShowRevToDateColumn;
}
```

Maybe it would be better to pass it as argument to the method `BuildGrid`.